# Retrieve the 1st and 5th column of a tab-separated file, convert the spaces in the 5th to tabs

Tags: text-processing, awk, cut, bioinformatics

I have a `tsv` file with tab-separated columns. I want to obtain the 5th column, which has space-separated values. Convert the space-separation to tab-separation and save as a new file.

Attempt:

```
cut -d"\t" -f"4" input.tsv
awk -v OFS="\t" '$1=$1' input.tsv > output.tsv
```

Input:

```
Composite_Element_REF   Gene_Symbol     Chromosome      Genomic_Coordinate      TCGA-KL-8323-01A-21D-2312-05 TCGA-KL-8324-01A-11D-2312-05 TCGA-KL-8325-01A-11D-2312-05 
cg00000027      RBL0    14      53468110        0.0545368833399913 0.635089208882213 0.0581022991274144
cg00000028      RBL1    15      53468111        0.0545366588241415 0.635089205024173 0.0581085373336217
cg00000029      RBL2    16      53468112        0.0545366588040571 0.635089205078394 0.0581085373332275
```

Expected output:

```
Composite_Element_REF   TCGA-KL-8323-01A-21D-2312-05    TCGA-KL-8324-01A-11D-2312-05    TCGA-KL-8325-01A-11D-2312-05
cg00000027     0.0545368833399913    0.635089208882213    0.0581022991274144
cg00000028    0.0545366588241415    0.635089205024173    0.0581085373336217
cg00000029    0.0545366588040571    0.635089205078394    0.0581085373332275
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is the 1st and 5th tab-delimited field from some input file `input.tsv`, and then change the embedded spaces in those fields into tabs, you can do that with `cut` and `tr` like so:

```bash
cut -f 1,5 input.tsv | tr ' ' '\t' >output.tsv
```

This first extracts the 1st and 5th fields from the input, then changes all space characters to tabs and writes the output to a file. If the 1st field is supposed to be unchanged, this assumes that this field does not contain spaces.

Since tab is the default delimiter for `cut`, we don't need to use the `-d` option.

Alternatively, with `awk`:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t" }
    {
        nf = split($5, a, " ")
        $0 = $1

        for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i) $(NF+1) = a[i]

        print
    }' input.tsv >output.tsv
```

This splits the 5th tab-delimited field on spaces and then overwrites all original fields with the 1st field.  The spilt-up fields are added after the first field in the loop, before outputting the resulting record.

With Miller (`mlr`), we can choose to read the input as header-less TSV (header-less, so that we simply treat the header as data), cut out the fields we're interested in and then recreate each record just like we did with `awk`, but shorter:

```bash
mlr --tsv -N put '$* = {1:$1, 2:splita($5, " ")}' input.tsv >output.tsv
```

The output from each of these commands would be

```
Composite_Element_REF   TCGA-KL-8323-01A-21D-2312-05    TCGA-KL-8324-01A-11D-2312-05    TCGA-KL-8325-01A-11D-2312-05
cg00000027      0.0545368833399913      0.635089208882213       0.0581022991274144
cg00000028      0.0545366588241415      0.635089205024173       0.0581085373336217
cg00000029      0.0545366588040571      0.635089205078394       0.0581085373332275
```

Note that I'm assuming that you want the header for the initial field, and that the lone `-05` on the second line of the input is a typo and should be attached to the end of the final field of the header line.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne 'put join "\t", .words.[0,4..*];'  file
```

Above is an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Here I assume (same as @Kusalananda♦) that *"the lone `-05` on the second line of the input is a typo and should be attached to the end of the final field of the header line."* (credit: @Kusalananda♦).

Briefly, the file is read linewise with the `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags. Raku's `.words` routine takes the `$_` topic (input line) and breaks it on whitespace into elements. Square brackets `[0,4..*]` select out the desired zero-indexed elements. These are `join`ed back together on `\t` tabs, giving the desired output.

Sample Input:

```
Composite_Element_REF   Gene_Symbol     Chromosome      Genomic_Coordinate      TCGA-KL-8323-01A-21D-2312-05 TCGA-KL-8324-01A-11D-2312-05 TCGA-KL-8325-01A-11D-2312-05 
cg00000027      RBL0    14      53468110        0.0545368833399913 0.635089208882213 0.0581022991274144
cg00000028      RBL1    15      53468111        0.0545366588241415 0.635089205024173 0.0581085373336217
cg00000029      RBL2    16      53468112        0.0545366588040571 0.635089205078394 0.0581085373332275
```

Sample Output:

```
Composite_Element_REF   TCGA-KL-8323-01A-21D-2312-05    TCGA-KL-8324-01A-11D-2312-05    TCGA-KL-8325-01A-11D-2312-05
cg00000027  0.0545368833399913  0.635089208882213   0.0581022991274144
cg00000028  0.0545366588241415  0.635089205024173   0.0581085373336217
cg00000029  0.0545366588040571  0.635089205078394   0.0581085373332275
```

---

It's fairly easy to deal with "short" lines, just add a conditional:

```
~$ raku -ne 'put join "\t", .words.[0,4..*] if .words.elems == 7;'  file
```

Finally, if you truly have a file with 2-different separators, you can manage them individually/consecutively:

```
~$ raku -ne '.split("\t", 5).[0,4].split(" ").join("\t").put;'   file
```

The final two solutions give the same "Sample Output" as above.

https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F '\t' '{gsub(OFS,FS,$5); print $1 FS $5}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW in reality I'd use [@PrapjhotSingh's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/760532/133219) but for some alternatives that may provide useful information on manipulating fields in general, read on...

To get the output you show from the input you show all you need is:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $5, $6, $7}' file
Composite_Element_REF   TCGA-KL-8323-01A-21D-2312-05    TCGA-KL-8324-01A-11D-2312-05    TCGA-KL-8325-01A-11D-2312-05
cg00000027      0.0545368833399913      0.635089208882213       0.0581022991274144
cg00000028      0.0545366588241415      0.635089205024173       0.0581085373336217
cg00000029      0.0545366588040571      0.635089205078394       0.0581085373332275
```

or, since I see you attempted using `$1=$1` in your code, you could do:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{$2=$3=$4=""; $0=$0; $1=$1} 1' file
Composite_Element_REF   TCGA-KL-8323-01A-21D-2312-05    TCGA-KL-8324-01A-11D-2312-05    TCGA-KL-8325-01A-11D-2312-05
cg00000027      0.0545368833399913      0.635089208882213       0.0581022991274144
cg00000028      0.0545366588241415      0.635089205024173       0.0581085373336217
cg00000029      0.0545366588040571      0.635089205078394       0.0581085373332275
```

where:

- `$2=$3=$4=""` sets those fields to null and reconstructs `$0`, where those fields still exist but are empty, replacing all blanks and tabs (which match the default `FS` we are using) with single tabs (the `OFS` we are using) so the blanks in the original `$5` become tabs as it gets separated into 3 fields, `$5`, `$6`, and `$7`.
- `$0=$0` re-splits `$0` into fields but doesn't change the white space between fields so those 3 fields are now gone but the multiple tabs between `$1` and the original `$5` (now `$2`, `$3`, and `$4`) still exist.
- `$1=$1` sets `$1` to itself which again reconstructs `$0` from it's fields, but now the multiple contiguous tabs (which again match the default `FS` we are using) are replaced by a single tab (the `OFS` we are using) resulting in the final output of 4 tab-separated fields.

You can see those different stages below, note the changes in spacing between fields and the change in the value of `NF` printed at the start of each line:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print NF ": " $0}' < <(printf 'a\tb\tc\td\te f g\n')
7: a    b       c       d       e f g
```

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{$2=$3=$4=""; print NF ": " $0}' < <(printf 'a\tb\tc\td\te f g\n')
7: a                            e       f       g
```

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{$2=$3=$4=""; $0=$0; print NF ": " $0}' < <(printf 'a\tb\tc\td\te f g\n')
4: a                            e       f       g
```

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{$2=$3=$4=""; $0=$0; $1=$1; print NF ": " $0}' < <(printf 'a\tb\tc\td\te f g\n')
4: a    e       f       g
```

Alternatively, in some awks, e.g. GNU awk, you could do either of these:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{$2=$5; $3=$6; $4=$7; NF=4} 1' file
awk -v OFS='\t' '{for (i=2; i<=4; i++) $i=$(i+3); NF=i-1} 1' file
```

where we're shifting the values of `$5` and later up 3 fields and then setting `NF` to 4 to remove the original `$5` and later, but setting `NF` is undefined behavior per POSIX so different awks will either honor that or ignore that or could do anything else.